# In WordPress, how do I add a folder name in front of a slug?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using this theme: http://www.eleventhemes.com/gridly/

In order for the pages to only show certain posts on certain pages it requires the category folder in front of the slug so if I have a page called graphic-design it has to be accessed this way: domain.com/category/graphic-design.  When I go to edit the page in WP it automatically removes the / after the word category.

How can I add a folder name in front of the page name?

Comment: What do you mean it removes the /? It sets the post url as domain.com/categorygraphic-design?

Comment: @JPLew Correct, it makes it like  domain.com/categorygraphic-design instead of  domain.com/category/graphic-design

Comment: I'm seeing http://www.eleventhemes.com/gridly/category/web-design/ ? Do you mean that when you edit a post and update it the URL is being rewritten without the trailing slash?

Comment: @benracicot, yes I want to have the same path domain.com/category/web-design.  But by default if i add a post under that category it doesn't show up as the page link.

Comment: @benracicot IN fact the category in the navigation menu appears this way: domain.com/category-name but it doesn't have category folder name in front of it by default.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a bug in the theme. My first guess is that there's a naming collision. I believe "category" is the slug Wordpress uses for displaying post categories, while the theme is trying to use "category" to rewrite page permalinks.

As an experiment, try editing Wordpress' built-in Category base option.

Try going to `Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks`, and at the bottom under "Category base" set the field to something besides "category", like "mycats" or whatever. For fun try setting it to "category" explicitly and see what happens.

Comment: I did try that but nothing happens.

Comment: Def a theme issue. I'd go straight to the author unless you've customized things. And if you have please tell us all about it here. so we can help better :)

Comment: I hard-coded into the theme the navigation menu.  The theme sucks!

Comment: so your theme determines page output based on the permalink? That is ridiculous theme design. I would grep your theme directory for "rewrite_rules". The offensive code won't be too far away.